# Is this the correct way to resolve conflicts from a git pull/merge?

Tags: git

I ran `git pull origin` and now I have some issues with merge my branch with a master.

Here's what I did:

1. commit all changes on my branch
2. git checkout master
3. git pull origin master
4. git checkout **my branch**
5. git merge master
6. open 'project.pbxproj' and removed all needed markers
7. open other conflict file and removed needed markers
8. git add for both files and git commit

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly acceptable way to resolve merge conflicts. I'll simply note that you don't need a local `master` branch -- you can omit steps 2, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE:*** This is updated thanks to an updated question...

So, when you do a pull, git will try to merge the existing changes and notify you of any conflicts. It looks like you are committing changes on a branch, we'll call it newBranch. You then checkout the local master branch and perform a pull. If you do a straight pull, git will combine the fetch and merge commands and only let you intervene if there are conflicts.

```
git push origin master
```

pushes your master branch to the origin remote. Similarly,

```
git pull origin master
```

Which would pull from the remote branch into your current branch.

I assume in step (4), you forgot to mention which branch you are checking out, but let's assume its that newBranch. You are trying to merge master INTO newBranch in step 5, which is also the opposite of what you usually want to do. Generally, you merge branches into the master branch after you test that a feature or change you made works. After you resolve any conflicts from the merge, it is committed as part of the merge. You can then push the merged master branch from origin to master.

Comment: The thing about pull and push is wrong. First it's the command, pull or push, then the remote (aliased as origin in this case) and then the ref, in this case the master branch. So "git push origin master" and "git pull origin master". And since it's the master branch it is default setup to track its origin/master, so only "git pull" and "git push" is needed.